# Blend file is 1.89 gigs but when opened is just blank

Tags: error, append, library

I recently ported a `.blend` and `.blend1` file I was working on from my mac to my PC using a USB.

Here's what I did:

- Packed all into blend
- Saved file
- Transferred into USB
  (both versions of blender are the same on both devices)

And after opening the file on PC it just showed the default stuff (cube, light, etc) just like it was a new file never touched, but when I inspected the file it had a lot of data in it, so I tried to append both files then reboot the save to the .blend1 file but both times it said `"error: File is not library"`

Edit:

so I went back to the mac version and when trying to append the file it shows there is no data, even though when opened everything is there and functional....

Comment: Do you see data if you go to the scripting tab and look under those nested tabs.  Tabs are located in the right side of the UI, middle section.

Comment: @WhisperingShiba nope, no data :/

Comment: sounds like its corruption.  Not sure how to proceed from there